# Rabbit will not cluster on ec2

Tags: rabbitmq

I am having server issues with getting rabbit to cluster.

I boot up two nodes on ec2.

On the the first node booted I do this.

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl reset
rabbitmqctl start_app

I boot another node.
sudo service rabbitmq-server stop
#Copy cookie from the first server booted
sudo su - -c 'echo -n "cookie" > /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie'
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl reset
rabbitmqctl cluster rabbit@server1
```

1) sever1 is running
2) What ports to need open?  I have 22, 4369, 5672

```
sudo rabbitmqctl cluster rabbit@aws-rabbit-server-east-development-20121102162143
Clustering node 'rabbit@aws-rabbit-server-east-development-20121103033005' with ['rabbit@aws-rabbit-server-east-development-20121102162143'] ...
Error: {no_running_cluster_nodes,['rabbit@aws-rabbit-server-east-development-20121102162143'],
                                 ['rabbit@aws-rabbit-server-east-development-20121102162143']}
```

What could possibility be missing from there docs or what what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem on EC2 with two windows machines. I eventually got it working but I'm not sure I did it in the correct way so there may be a better solution.

The issue I found was that the two nodes could not see each other when trying to cluster. Each time you start a Rabbit node it seemed to be assigned a port number dynamically.

This obviously makes it very difficult to know which port to open up in the security group so to solve this, I restricted the range of ports Rabbit chose from when assigning the port. I restricted this to a range of 1 port on each node so I always know which port was being assigned.

The easiest way I found to do this was by editing the sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat file.

find the line **-kernel inet_default_connect_options "[{nodelay,true}]" ^**

add the following two lines to the file underneath:

**-kernel inet_dist_listen_min ##### ^
-kernel inet_dist_listen_max ##### ^**

replacing ##### with your chosen port number.

So you should now open up the following ports:

5672 - RabbitMQ’s listening port

4369 - Erlang Port Mapper Daemon

##### - the chosen port number for the Erlang nodes to communicate via

Because Erlang does not recognise FQDNs you may need to modify the hosts file on all the servers to make sure they are all able to resolve all the Erlang node name to an IP address, e.g.

123.123.123.111 NODE1

123.123.123.222 NODE2

once this is done you should then be able to see each node from the other. you can do this by using calling the following from the command line (replacing rabbit@NODE2 with whichever node you want to see)

**rabbitmqctl status -n rabbit@NODE2**

Hope this give you some help, I'm no expert but found this got things working for me!